# How to stop the sprite's movement when it touches the edges of the screen with Pygame?

Tags: pygame

I created my first sprite with Pygame and managed to make it move with keyboard keys. However, when it encounters the edges of the screen, it keeps moving beyond them, disappearing from the screen. I would like to make it stop when it touches the edges, how can I do it?

This is my code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jPyQ.jpg

Comment: Please never post images of your code, insert the code directly into the message (copy, paste, select it and press Ctrl+K to indent it).

Answer (score 2):

Heres an example of making the walls solid with an SWIDTH (Screen width) variable, and `pygame.math.Vector2`.

```
    if self.rect.right >= SWIDTH:
        self.rect.right = SWIDTH
        self.vel.x = 0
        self.anim_type = 0
        self.accelerating = False

        self.pos.x = self.rect.left

    elif self.rect.left <= 0:
         self.rect.left = 1
         self.vel.x = 0
         self.anim_type = 0
         self.accelerating = False

        self.pos.x = self.rect.left
```